# Сортировка Json массива, вывод большего значения, с последующей записью в БД

Tags: php

День добрый.
Помогите разобраться, если не сложно.
В общем есть json массив

```
[  
   {  
      "text":"text",
      "text":"text",
      ...
      "last_episode_time":"2015-11-22 12:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "text":"text",
      "text":"text",
      ...
      "last_episode_time":"2015-11-22 13:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "text":"text",
      "text":"text",
      ...
      "last_episode_time":"2015-11-20 14:00:00"
   }
]
```

Получаю его след. образом

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents("http://site.ru/api/test.json");
$content = json_decode($url, true);
?>
```

Необходимо сравнить значения полей `last_episode_time`
и вывести большее т.е. `2015-11-22 13:00:00`

Далее это значение записать в бд

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "test";
$dbname = "test";
$id = "770";
$date = "2015-11-22 13:00:00";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "UPDATE dle_post SET date='$date' WHERE id=$id";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "good";
} else {
    echo "bad: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

И по поводу записи в бд, можно ли сделать проверку, что бы каждый раз не перезаписывать БД.

Спасибо.

Comment: А что вы уже сделали для решения проблемы сами? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: Сам? Состряпал данный говнокод, с json и php познакомился часа 3 назад. Все что нашел в сети, может плохо искал. А не получилось сделать выборку, отсортировать и вывести значение.

Comment: Ну значит так и говорите: "_Задачу сам сделать не смог, напишите, пожалуйста за меня. Привожу один из примеров кода, который не делает то, что мне нужно._"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приветствую! Если проверку во время записи, то вот так:

```
$sql = "UPDATE dle_post SET date='$date' WHERE id=$id AND date!='$date'";
```

Если проверку до записи, то:

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://site.ru/api/test.json");
$cache = '';
if (file_exists("test.json")) {
    $cache = file_get_contents("test.json");
}
if ($cache != $url) {
    file_put_contents("test.json", $url);
    //а здесь Ваш код, который обновляет данные в таблице.
}
```

Вариант - получать каждый раз дату из кэшировать ее таким же макаром. Это освободит память, но займет время.

И по поводу первого вопроса, который я увидел вторым =)

```
$dates = [];
foreach ($content as $row) {
   $dates[] = $row->last_episode_time; //собираем даты в массив
}
rsort($dates); //сортируем в обратном порядке, большая-первая
$date = array_shift($dates); //вуаля
```

Comment: Вы ответили только на пол вопроса

Comment: Это верно. Не заметил первую часть.